# Create a column based on successive conditions in R using dplyr

Tags: dplyr

I would like to create a variable by applying different criteria successively.
The criteria are the following:

```
ungho <- unghoraw %>% 
# Criteria 1:
mutate(choice1 = ifelse(UN_miss=="No data","GHO",ifelse(GHO_miss=="No data","UN",NA)))%>%
# Criteria 2:
mutate(choice2 = ifelse(diff_qual=="no diff","GHO",NA))%>%
# Criteria 3:
mutate(choice3 = ifelse(nb_years_gho>=nb_years_un,"GHO",ifelse(nb_years_un>nb_years_gho,"UN",NA)))%>%
# Criteria 4:
mutate(choice4 = ifelse(dec_gho>=dec_un,"GHO",ifelse(dec_un>dec_gho,"UN",NA)))%>%
# Criteria 5:
mutate(choice5 = ifelse(last_year_gho>=last_year_un,"GHO",ifelse(last_year_un>last_year_gho,"UN",NA)))%>%
```

I would like to apply criteria 1, then if criteria 1 is missing - criteria 2, then if criteria 1 and 2 are missing - criteria 3, ect.. I have tried this but it does not work:

```
# FINAL CHOICE BASED ON CRITERIA
mutate(final_choice=ifelse(!is.na(choice1),choice1,ifelse(!is.na(choice2),choice2,ifelse(!is.na(choice3,choice4,ifelse(!is.na(choice4),choice5,NA))))) %>%
```

I have tried mutate_cond as well but did not succeed in making it work at all..

Is there a way of creating such a variable in a simple way rather than trying to nest several ifelse?

Thanky you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
mutate(final_choice=choice1) %>%
mutate_cond(is.na(final_choice),final_choice=choice2) %>%
mutate_cond(is.na(final_choice),final_choice=choice3) %>%
mutate_cond(is.na(final_choice),final_choice=choice4) %>%
mutate_cond(is.na(final_choice),final_choice=choice5) %>%
```